# why no examples of video output in early computers (before desktop era)

Tags: history

*Moved to https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23930/ ([Retrocomputing community](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com)).*

---

Why was the serial terminal the dominant modality for interactive computer input and output up until the rise of desktop systems, with no earlier widespread adoption of the  design later used by desktop systems, of the host system generating video signal for direct connection to a monitor?

Sources explain that early video terminals emerged as a replacement, in many cases a drop-in replacement, for teletypewriter-style terminals, later evolving to acquire features such as interactive editing and   block transfer. However, no prominent examples appear of a minicomputer or microcomputer, predating the emergence of desktop system, that supplied video output directly to a display device, obviating the need for memory and processing on the peripheral.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Unix Linux, will result in answers that are opinion-based, and more information on the subject can be found via Google.

Comment: Maybe https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place.

Comment: Even the [first home computers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800) came with no display.  I wonder what, if any, commercial drive there could have been to attach a display to a mainframe. I guess (but can't prove) that the first displays were developed for enthusiasts rather than satisfying a business need.

Comment: I don't know why you say they didn't exist.  Sure, teletypes and even CRT serial terminals were common, but CROs (cathode ray oscilloscopes) were used on very early computers (1950s and 1960s).   The 2nd or 3rd gen (depnding on how you count generations) **home** computers (Apple ][, TRS-80, commodore pet, etc) all had CRT output  circuitry built-in (and it was common to plug them into a TV set).  It was possible to buy/build them for earlier home computers too, like IMSAI and Altair systems.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bandwidth issue. In 1967, I communicated with the Carnegie institute of Technology mainframes at 110 baud (bits/second) over Teletype models 33 and 35, at 134.5 baud with an IBM 2741 clone over an acoustic coupler, at 300-9600 baud with a Glass keypunch (DEC VT100 or clone). None of the early modems' speeds could support computer graphics, although the VT100-VT200 line could address a 24x80 or 24x132 character screen. It was only when "terminals" smartened up to "nodes" on the network (and X11 got invented) that remote graphics became practical. Serial protocols are easy for dumb (or early) devices to communicate.

Comment: A graphics module, such as the early desktop graphics cards (before graphics were integrated into the main board, and before digital video was transferred by digital signals such as DVI-D and HDMI) does not transmit a digital representation of a graphics roster, but an analog video signal such as the one that had been produced by television tuners, game systems, and cassette decks. The question is why no design was in use for the host computer generating a video signal for display on a desktop monitor.

Comment: @epl you are mistaken. Computers are digital (period). The analogue video cards would still need to communicate with the main board (motherboard) as a digital representation of a graphics roster. The card would be responsible for the digital to analogue conversion.

Comment: Early computer video monitors were entirely analogue.  For IBM-compatible PCs, [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) had been the standard connection for monitors before being superseded by DVI-D and HDMI. The transition to digital signaling was largely driven by the replacement of CRT display devices by flat-screen technologies, as well as the rise of digital television signals and their convergence with computer video.

Comment: @epl you are making me feel old talking like that transition was old history. I grew up using a VGA CRT (all analogue) and sat on my uncle's knee playing with a green screen BBC.   **now the important thing** is that the computer processes the graphics in 24 bit digital raster (earlier 8 but or monochrome) and the graphics card on the computer converts that to analogue. The fact that any analogue was involved isn't useful to answering the question because that's just an implementation detail of the graphics card.

Comment: The question is why no design was employed in which the host system would generate an (analog) video signal for direct attachment of a monitor receiving the signal, the same as has been the design for desktop computers, instead of integrating the video signal generation into a serial terminal receiving digital character data.